# Excel SUMIF/SUMPRODUCT with Dates Identifier?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

So I am currently working with a spreadsheet of data that has info on a set of loans and how they payback over time. I'm trying to create a table that sums their payback based on what month they were started in. For example, for loans started in April, how much did we get back at the end of April... how much at the end of May? I need to do this in a dynamic way for a large set but Idk where to start with this one. I presume it would be a variation on SUMIF or SUMPRODUCT. Here's a sample of dummy data and the table I'm trying to fill out. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi @fruityflex ,, check my post I've solved the issue,,, I hope it work for you,,, if yes then U may accept it as ANSWER as well UP vote ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try the following formula, `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($B$2:$B$14)=MONTH($D18))*($C$1:$Q$1<=EOMONTH($D18,(COLUMN(E$17)-COLUMN($D$17)-1)))*($C$1:$Q$1>EOMONTH($D18,COLUMN(E$17)-COLUMN($D$17)-2))*($C$2:$Q$14))`.

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm for the above data, but when I tried to recreate it with a separate sheet, I get #Value errors which I isolated to be coming from the last argument for the sum array. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please explain more about "the last argyment for the sum array"? I find an article "[How to correct a #VALUE! error in the SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-sumproduct-function-bb91e4f3-a7c9-40ee-bdc7-0b1ecfd68c5f)", you may have a look, please ensure the scope referenced is correct.

Comment: if I wanted to do the same thing but instead group by year only (as opposed to month & year), how would I go about that. I.E cells D19-D21 being 2018,2019,2020,2021

Comment: @fruityflex Do you still want to keep "After 1 Month", "After 2 Months" and etc? If yes, I would suggest you use another formula under the previous tabe to get the sum of one specific year for "After 1 Month", "After 2 Months" and other columns. Such as "2018" in cell D26, formula in E26 `=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR($D$18:$D25)=$D26)*(E$18:E25))` . Then you may hide the rows with month & year.

Answer (score 0):

*With little modification in output format what you are trying can be achieved.*

[image]

---

**N.B.**

- For better understanding & visualization I've taken few data sets,
  you may extend it as much is needed.
- Formula in cell B30 & fill across:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(($A$21:$A$26=$A30)*($C$20:$L$20>=B$29)*($C$20:$L$20<=EOMONTH(B$29,0))*($C$21:$L$26))
  ```
- From B29 to H29 fill first date of related month & apply `mmm-yyyy`
  cell format.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.